# How to send data from Arduino to Unity android game?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, bluetooth

I have recently made a game in Unity. However, for controlling the game, I need to send data from Arduino to the game using Bluetooth. Can anyone please help me with a way to communicate between the two?

I am using HC-05 module and doesn't want to use any of the unity assets which are very costly.Can you please tell an alternative method of communication?

Comment: Are you playing unity game on android device ?

Comment: This is quite a lot for a single question. try tackling your problem one step at a time ; You probably know how to handle the communication on the part of the arduino & HC05. What you need now is a way to read the virtual COM port (assuming windows here) on your PC from unity (C#) (or how to handle bluetooth data communication on android in unity (C#)

Comment: If you are actively developing and debugging, going for the PC solution *first* might be easier.

Comment: on a sidenote, there is plenty of info about that ;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532244/accessing-bluetooth-data-via-serialport-in-c-sharp

http://justkiel.com/wordpress/?p=1335

Comment: @TimothyGroote Your links and COM port suggest won't work since OP wants to do this between Android and Arduino via bluetooth not between Android and PC.

Comment: @OP, Since you don't want to use any paid Asset, you have to make one your self. People won't do that for you for free here. It's your job to write a code then ask a question if it doesn't work and also provide that code. *Download Android Studio, learn Java, use Java to connect to the Arduino via bluetooth. Write a function that sends and receives data between the two. Once it's all working, compile the Java code into a ".jar" or ".arr" plugin then call it from C#(Unity Side).* That's it.

Comment: @Programmer i don't think you've read the entire comment.